# How to encrypt cookie generated by servlet using Filter?

Tags: java, servlet-filters

When the servlet generates the cookie and adds it in the response headers, I want to encrypt the same cookie using Java Filter and pass the encrypted cookie to client. Moreover how to access the HTML content of the response generated by the servlet using Filter.??

Comment: If you use SSL then, I think you dont need to encrypt the cookie value

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively/additionally set the [HttpOnly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) attribute of the cookie. This disables access of JavaScript to the cookie. *(The problem with cookies is their limited length, and a thorough encryption costs.)*

Decrypting the cookies coming from the request is simply calling `getCookies()` and passing a [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) with a new `Cookie[]` in an overriden `getCookies`.

Encrypting the response cookies goes almost the same: a [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) is passed along the chain, intercepting the `addCookie` by overriding it.

Comment: For overridding addCookie we need to retrieve the data of the cookie set by the servlet how to do that ??

Comment: it works only when web server is requesting cookies ... but how to encrypt it when the server is setting the cookie value ??